# Conditional set onTap?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want make tap behavior different for different user. How I can make conditional for onPress so for one user type he must tap, but for other user he must double tap?

For example I want do:

```
InkWell(
if (userType1) {
          onTap: onPress,
} else {
onDoubleTap: onPress,
}
          child:
```

This is possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```dart
InkWell(
          onTap: userType1 ? onPress : null,
          onDoubleTap: !userType1 ? onPress : null,
          child: Container()
       )
```